# awk line 3: /dev/sda: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I do feel stupid, but can someone please explain to me, why this:

> ```
> current="`smartctl -a /dev/sda | awk '/Serial Number/ {printf "%s%s%s %s ", "\033[31m","/dev/sda","\033[0m",$3}'`"
> current2="`$current | awk '{print $2}'`"
> ```

leads to "/dev/sda: No such file or directory" while this:

```
current2="`smartctl -a /dev/sda | awk '/Serial Number/ {printf "%s%s%s %s ", "\033[31m","/dev/sda","\033[0m",$3}' | awk '{print $2}'`"
```

is working and this one:

> ```
> current="`smartctl -a /dev/sda | awk '/Serial Number/ {printf "%s%s%s %s ", "\033[31m","/dev/sda","\033[0m",$3}'`"
> current2="`echo $current | awk '{print $2}'`"
> ```

also working

Comment: A good read which could solve your problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: The problem is that the things in a pipeline (`thing1 | thing2`) must be *commands* (like `echo $current` and `awk '{print $2}'`), not just pieces of data (like just `$current`). When you use `$current | ...`, the shell tries to treat the content of `$current` as a command, and it fails. Also, you should double-quote variable references to avoid weird parsing problems (e.g. `echo "$current"` instead of just `echo $current`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot some of these problems, and also have other useful suggestions.

Comment: Two of the shell programming fundamentals you're currently missing are described at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code, `current` stores the result of the code inside `` `...` ``, and as a result, has the string something like `/dev/sda 502...`.

In the subsequent line, you have `` `$current` | awk ... ``. Now, when the shell sees this, it replaces `$current` with the string `/dev/sda ...` and tries to *run* it; i.e., you are in effect asking the shell to *execute* `/dev/sda 502...`, which leads to an error.

Comment: But both $current and awk inside ``

Comment: Yes, but that does not change the analyiss. You are trying to _execute_ `/dev/sda ... | awk ...`, which does not make sense. This is analogous to that you're trying `input.txt | awk ...`. You would rather want `cat input.txt | awk ...` or `awk ... input.txt`. You don't just write the name of an input file (or in your case the input variable `$current`) as a _command_.

Comment: Roger, thank you, for spending time on helping me

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad it helped.